# Tie vector item with listview item

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vector, c++-cli

How to tie the vector item with listview item? When the listview item is selected and for example, clicked on the delete button, I want to get the item pointer of my vector which ties with selected item in listview, and use function like this:

```
class x
{
  int a;
}

void Delete(vector<x*> vec, x* item)
{
  for(int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    if (vec[i] == item)
        vec.erase(i):
  }
}

int main()
{ vector<x*> vec;
  //selecting item in list view and click the delete button
  Delete(vec, /*get item from listview*/);
}
```

And I need to do another function with this selected item.